# Mock method drawn to interface for searching null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, boolean, mockito

I have an method which i must drawn to interface and write test for searching nullPointerExc. Here is the method:

```
boolean hasDocsChangedRequired (GroupProvider currentGroupAdm, GroupProvider groupAdm) { 
    return !currentGroupAdm.getDocs().equals(groupAdm.getDocs()); 
}
```

Somewhere in getDocs method is null.

I created the interface Changer with method:

```
boolean hasDocsChangedRequired();
```

And I implement this to class with the same body method as previously with SOLID rules

I have question how to good write test using mockito to fully cover this boolean function?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'which i must drawn to interface'? Also can you show us what you have tried to solve this so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pawel you can write test for checking your function like this, i am assuming that function is not static.
If you want to make it static , then you simply have to remove these 2 lines

```
@InjectMocks
ChangerImpl changer;
```

And in place of "changer" you have call corresponding Implemented class.
Hope this helps.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestSampleTest {

  @InjectMocks
  ChangerImpl changer;

  @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
  public void test1(){

    GroupProvider currentGroupAdm = mock(GroupProvider.class);
    doReturn(null).when(currentGroupAdm).getDocs();

    GroupProvider groupAdm = mock(GroupProvider.class);
    oReturn("sample2").when(groupAdm).getDocs();

    changer.hasDocsChangedRequired(currentGroupAdm, groupAdm);
  }

  @Test
  public void test2(){

    GroupProvider currentGroupAdm = mock(GroupProvider.class);
    doReturn("sample1").when(currentGroupAdm).getDocs();

    GroupProvider groupAdm = mock(GroupProvider.class);
    doReturn("sample2").when(groupAdm).getDocs();

    Assert.assertThat(changer.hasDocsChangedRequired(currentGroupAdm, groupAdm), is(true));
  }

  @Test
  public void test3(){

    GroupProvider currentGroupAdm = mock(GroupProvider.class);
    doReturn("sample1").when(currentGroupAdm).getDocs();

    GroupProvider groupAdm = mock(GroupProvider.class);
    doReturn("sample1").when(groupAdm).getDocs();

    Assert.assertThat(changer.hasDocsChangedRequired(currentGroupAdm, groupAdm), is(false));
  }

}
```

Comment: Just throwing a ton of code at people, without any explanations ... not exactly how you write a good answer. Instead of spending time on writing code for other people, you should consider to rather *explain* to them how to solve their problems. For example, when something about the inject goes wrong, the OP will have no idea what things arent working.

Answer (score 0):

The output of your method

```
boolean hasDocsChangedRequired (GroupProvider currentGroupAdm, GroupProvider groupAdm) { 
    return !currentGroupAdm.getDocs().equals(groupAdm.getDocs()); 
}
```

solely depends on your two input objects.

In other words: you **only** have to provide input objects that give what you want to give for a specific test. Meaning: you probably want to write a test where `currentGroupAdm.getDocs()` gives something that is equal to `groupAdm.getDocs()`, and one where the two calls give a non-equal result.

Ideally, you don't need to mock anything here.